# What does this SQL statement produce?

Tags: sql

I am having trouble finding documentation about this specific statement

```
SELECT IF (count(f.id)=0,1,0) as flgNew
FROM table f ON ...
WHERE ...
```

the table is joined with other tables and should return 1 if the entry in `f` is found or 0 if it has not been found.

So what does  IF (count(f.id)=0,1,0) do?

Comment: May be IF statement to translate regardless of count show 1. and same can be achieve by case.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's basically the same as the following `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN count(f.id) = 0
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
       END AS flgNew
...
```

It checks to see if the expression `count(f.id) = 0` is true, and returns the value `1` if it is, and `0` if it is not.

You can read more on the `IF()` function in the official docs here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if

Comment: Ok, that's reasonable!